# SSD appears in BIOS but it doesn't appear in the terminal

Tags: 22.04, ssd, bios, automount

I have a brand new Ubuntu PC with three SSDs connected and they are shown in the BIOS.

[image: bios img link]

However only two of them are shown in the terminal.

[image: terminal img link]

Running `udisksctl status` I get:

```
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Samsung SSD 980 PRO 1TB   5B2QGXA7  S5GXNF1R846481E      nvme0n1 
Samsung SSD 980 PRO 2TB   5B2QGXA7  S69ENX0W217972R      nvme1n1
```

Comment: Do they all have latest firmware from Samsung? Post this in question above. `udisksctl status` And compare to latest on Samsung web site. https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/ Do not use Magician unless you also have Windows. I just downloaded ISO & created bootable drive & installed update.

Comment: @oldfred answer updated with the terminal output. I'm checking the link you sent now

Comment: Looks like firmware is most current. Are all three connected with standard NVMe ports? Not seen many systems with multiple NVMe ports. What model Asus motherboard?